# Resize polygon in to fill in Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, polygon

How can i resize Polygon which is placed in Canvas so it fills that canvas?

I don't want to change values of polygon points, I just want it to be displayed inside of canvas in case polygon coordinates are too large, too small or out of screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the chance to replace the Canvas with a Grid? If so just set the `Stretch` attribute of the polygon, e.g. `Uniform` keeps the aspect ratio:

```
  <Grid Width="297" Height="159">
    <Polygon Points="10,110 110,110 110,10" Fill="Blue" Stretch="Uniform" />
  </Grid>
```

Comment: It works for polygons with small number of points, unfortunately for large number (in my case around 250.000) it doesn't work.
But I guess that's not your answers fault. Should I mark it as an answer then?

Comment: As you like. I agree having this huge amount of points the Polygon isn't the right aproach. One way usually is to reduce the number of points without losing information (the shape). The point skip algorithm depends on the data. I had a similar problem a while ago and it turned out that a costly point skip algorithm is still faster than drawing all the (unnecessary) points.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this problem recently and worked out a solid solution:

```
<Canvas x:Name="CanvasName">
    <Polygon Points="{Binding Path=PointCollectionName}" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Black"
        Width={Binding ElementName=CanvasName, Path=ActualWidth}"
        Height={Binding ElementName=CanvasName, Path=AcutalHeight}"/>
</Canvas>
```